# MODX Revolution - elRTE outputs lines of text instead of page content

Tags: modx, elrte

I think something causes conflict in my MODX Revolution 2.2.4 installation. Before when I used TinyMCE everything was OK but when I installed elRTE and and set it up as a default rich text editor in System Settings it gives a strange output- when I click any ressource to edit, it displays just these line of text:

```
  modX Object ( [context] => modContext_mysql Object ( [config] => Array ( [allow_tags_in_post] => 1 [modRequest.class] => modManagerRequest ) [aliasMap] => Array ( ) [resourceMap] => Array ( ) [webLinkMap] => Array ( ) [eventMap] => Array ( [OnDocFormPrerender] => Array ( [3] => 3 ) [OnManagerPageBeforeRender] => Array ( [3] => 3 ) [OnRichTextBrowserInit] => Array ( [11] => 11 ) [OnRichTextEditorInit] => Array ( [11] => 11 ) [OnRichTextEditorRegister] => Array ( [11] => 11 ) [OnSiteRefresh] => Array ( [6] => 6 ) [OnTVInputPropertiesList] => Array ( [3] => 3 ) [OnTVInputRenderList] => Array
```

...and so on.
On the other hand, when I install elRTE on clean Revo install, all works fine.
Anyone knows what might be causing a problem?

Answer (score 0):

You have removed TinyMCE before installing elRTE?

Comment: At first I din't remove TinyMCE as I thought they would both work depending on which one I choose in the settings. Then I removed as I thouught it was causing a problem but it's still not working unfortunately! Is it possible that some TinyMCE settings are still there not entirely removed and this is causing a problem?

Comment: Try updating modx, maybe it will help.